# how to convert row to column in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can somebody help me with this SQL Query.

In the following table, RESPONSES counts how many times SEGMENT has
responded on CHECKED date.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST (ID INT, SEGMENT CHAR(1),RESPONSES
INT,CHECKED SMALLDATETIME)
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES (1,'A',0,'2009-05-01')
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES (2,'B',1,'2009-05-01')
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES (3,'C',0,'2009-05-01')
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES (4,'A',0,'2009-05-02')
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES (5,'B',2,'2009-05-02')
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES (6,'C',1,'2009-05-02')
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES (7,'A',1,'2009-05-03')
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES (8,'B',0,'2009-05-03')
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES (9,'C',2,'2009-05-03')
```

Write a query to summarise total RESPONSES for each SEGMENT and each
CHECKED date, shown in following format:

```
CHECKED      A      B       C
2009-5-01    0      1       0
2009-5-02    0      2       1
2009-5-03    1      0       2
```

Do NOT hard-code segment names (i.e. “A”, “B”, “C”) into your solution, so the
solution remains functional if more segments are added (e.g. “D”) or segments are
renamed (e.g. “A” -> “X”).

Comment: This smacks of homework. Is it?

Comment: @paul - It's an interview question and I can't answer it :P

Comment: The short answer is that it cannot be done natively in the SQL language. It either requires a vendor specific extension (e.g. Access' Transform keyword) or dynamic SQL which should be done outside of T-SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this on [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301613/inverse-row-to-column/5301689#comment-6006334):  If using SQL Server 2005 or greater...

```
DECLARE  @test TABLE
(
    ID INT, 
    SEGMENT CHAR(1),
    RESPONSES INT,
    CHECKED SMALLDATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @test VALUES (1,'A',0,'2009-05-01')
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (2,'B',1,'2009-05-01')
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (3,'C',0,'2009-05-01')
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (4,'A',0,'2009-05-02')
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (5,'B',2,'2009-05-02')
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (6,'C',1,'2009-05-02')
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (7,'A',1,'2009-05-03')
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (8,'B',0,'2009-05-03')
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (9,'C',2,'2009-05-03')


SELECT * FROM 
(    
    SELECT  SEGMENT,
            RESPONSES,
            CHECKED
    FROM @test
) AS subquery 
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(responses) 
    FOR SEGMENT IN ([a],[b],[c])
) AS pivotquery
```

---

**Dynamic SQL Example**

```
CREATE TABLE ##test
(
    ID INT, 
    SEGMENT CHAR(1),
    RESPONSES INT,
    CHECKED SMALLDATETIME
)

INSERT INTO ##test VALUES (1,'A',0,'2009-05-01')
INSERT INTO ##test VALUES (2,'B',1,'2009-05-01')
INSERT INTO ##test VALUES (3,'C',0,'2009-05-01')
INSERT INTO ##test VALUES (4,'A',0,'2009-05-02')
INSERT INTO ##test VALUES (5,'B',2,'2009-05-02')
INSERT INTO ##test VALUES (6,'C',1,'2009-05-02')
INSERT INTO ##test VALUES (7,'A',1,'2009-05-03')
INSERT INTO ##test VALUES (8,'B',0,'2009-05-03')
INSERT INTO ##test VALUES (9,'C',2,'2009-05-03')

DECLARE @SQLa VARCHAR(255),
        @SQLb VARCHAR(255),
        @SQLc VARCHAR(255)

SET @SQLa =
'SELECT * FROM 
(    
    SELECT  SEGMENT,
            RESPONSES,
            CHECKED
    FROM ##test
) AS subquery 
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(responses) 
    FOR SEGMENT IN ('

SET @SQLc = ')
) AS pivotquery'

SELECT @sqlB = STUFF(
(
    SELECT ',[' + SEGMENT + ']'
    FROM ##test WITH (NOLOCK)
    GROUP BY SEGMENT
    FOR XML PATH('')
),1, 1, '')

EXECUTE (@SQLa + @SQLb + @SQLc)

DROP TABLE ##test
```

Comment: You can use dynamic SQL (or a function) to get the column names: A,B,C - let me know if you'd like an example.

Comment: @dan- Please let me know the example. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @kevin: Sorry for the delay, huge meeting last night.

Comment: Although, I didn't realize that this was an interview question until now.  Does that mean I get the job? :)

Comment: You are overqualified. That means you don't get it :P

Comment: It's a shame that I'm happy where I am... :D

Answer (score 2):

You need to use dynamic SQL. See this [blog post](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx) for an example. [Another example,](http://www.sqlprof.com/blogs/sqldev/archive/2008/04/12/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005-2008.aspx) different blog, same approach.

If your columns are static and you're using SQL Server 2005 and higher you can use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) feature to perform this type of query.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the only other way. See the links edited into my answer.

Comment: Dynamic query is the only way. With PIVOT the columns to be pivoted have to be listed in the query i.e. the PIVOT query can't take care of "dynamic segments" i.e. last condition "Do NOT hard-code segment names.." can't be fulfilled with static statement.

Comment: @amit_g: Good point. I shuffled my answer around to highlight that fact.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select Checked
    , Sum( Case When Segment = 'A' Then 1 Else 0 End ) As A
    , Sum( Case When Segment = 'B' Then 1 Else 0 End ) As B
    , Sum( Case When Segment = 'C' Then 1 Else 0 End ) As C
From #Test
Group By Checked
```

This type of query is often called a crosstab query. The above solution assumes you want to statically declare which columns you want to see. If you want to dynamically determine the columns, then what you seek is a dynamic crosstab and it cannot be done natively in the SQL language. The SQL language was not designed for dynamic column generation. The solution is to build the query in your middle-tier.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I don't want a fix column . Is there any other way ?? If it's  K,L and M , i don't want to rename  A,B and C to K,L and M.

Comment: @Kevin - As I amended to the bottom of my answer, it cannot be done natively in the SQL language. The only solution is dynamic SQL which should not be done in T-SQL.