# Basic Pivot tables

Tags: t-sql

I have data in the following table:

```
select person_name, appointment_id, unique_encounter, enounter_code 
from appointment

person_name appointment_id  unique_encounter    enounter_code   
----------- --------------  ----------------    -------------
Mike        123             A1                  CG
Mike        123             A1                  DT  
John        458             1F                  CG  
Bill        555             AB                  AJ
Joe         197             ZZ                  CG
Joe         197             ZZ                  AJ
Joe         197             ZZ                  DT
```

I'm trying to write a query to achieve the following results:

```
person_name appointment_id  unique_encounter    enounter_code_1 enounter_code_2 enounter_code_3     
----------- --------------  ----------------    -------------   --------------- ---------------
Mike        123             A1                  New                             Deleted
John        458             1F                  New 
Bill        555             AB                                  Updated
Joe         197             ZZ                  New             Updated         Deleted
```

My query is not working: Can some possible help. Thanks

```
select person_name, appointment_id, unique_encounter 
    ,Case when enounter_code = 'CG' then 'New' else '' End as enounter_code_1   
    ,Case when enounter_code = 'AJ' then 'Updated' else '' End as enounter_code_2
    ,Case when enounter_code = 'DT' then 'Deleted' else '' End as enounter_code_3

from appointment
group by person_name, appointment_id, unique_encounter
```

Comment: I was able to figure it out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652334/how-to-convert-row-to-column-in-sql/5653301#5653301

Answer (score 0):

Have you right to Pivot the data.

try this out its a different view.

```
create table #temp1
(
person_name nvarchar(50)
,appointment_id nvarchar(50)
,unique_encounter nvarchar(50)
,enounter_code nvarchar(50)
)

insert into #temp1
(person_name, appointment_id, unique_encounter, enounter_code)
Values
('Mike',123,'A1','CG')
,('Mike',123,'A1','DT')
,('John',458,'1F','CG')
,('Bill',555,'AB','AJ')
,('Joe',197,'ZZ','CG')
,('Joe',197,'ZZ','AJ')
,('Joe',197,'ZZ','DT')



select *
from 
(
  select person_name, appointment_id, unique_encounter, enounter_code
  from #temp1
) s
pivot
(
Max(person_name)
  for enounter_code in ([CG], [AJ], [DT])
  ) pvt;
```

Try it out:
https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/edit/659696