# Turning columns into rows (ORACLE)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to convert my query columns in rows.
This is my query:

```sql
select sum(CASE WHEN 
                     t.price < 5000
                THEN t.price END) AS RANGE1,
       sum(CASE WHEN 
                     t.price between 5000 and 10000 
                THEN t.price END) AS RANGE2,
       sum(CASE WHEN 
                     t.price > 10000
                THEN t.price END) AS RANGE3
From
      cars t
Where
      t.status = 3
```

The result is like this:

```SQL
RANGE1   RANGE2    RANGE3
-------  -------  --------
50000     75000      84000
```

I want the result is as follows:

```SQL
RANGE    TOTAL    
------- -------  
RANGE1   50000    
RANGE2   75000      
RANGE3   84000
```

Comment: Here is a thread with some examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858079/how-to-convert-columns-into-rows-in-oracle?lq=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select 
        'RANGE1' RANGE,
        sum(CASE WHEN 
                     t.price < 5000
                THEN t.price END) AS total
From
      cars t
Where
      t.status = 3 

union all

select 
        'RANGE2' RANGE,
       sum(CASE WHEN 
                     t.price between 5000 and 10000 
                THEN t.price END) AS total
From
      cars t
Where
      t.status = 3 

union all

select  
        'RANGE3' RANGE,
       sum(CASE WHEN 
                     t.price > 10000
                THEN t.price END) AS total
From
      cars t
Where
      t.status = 3
```