# Merge two consecutive rows into a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assuming that, I have a table something like this :

| EmployeeCode | EntryType | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC200413 | IN | 8:48AM |
| ABC200413 | OUT | 4:09PM |
| ABC200413 | IN | 4:45PM |
| ABC200413 | OUT | 6:09PM |
| ABC200413 | IN | 7:45PM |
| ABC200413 | OUT | 10:09PM |

Now I want to convert my data something like this :

| EmployeeCode | IN_TIME | OUT_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC200413 | 8:48AM | 4:09PM |
| ABC200413 | 4:45PM | 6:09PM |
| ABC200413 | 7:45PM | 10:09PM |

Is there any way I can achieve this using SQL server query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858079/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-in-oracle

Comment: You are assuming that the rows in your table have a natural order. How do you intend to ensure this?

Comment: The link posted by Koushik Roy doesn't answer the question, because our poster here can have any number of IN's and OUT's per customer. The supplied answer assumes a constant number of three rows.

Comment: @MarkRoberts We managed this from the code level, so everything in this table will be in this pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided `mytable` contains only valid pairs of in / out events

```
select EmployeeCode, 
  max(case EntryType when 'IN' then TIME end ) IN_TIME,
  max(case EntryType when 'OUT' then TIME end ) OUT_TIME
from ( 
   select EmployeeCode, EntryType, TIME,
     row_number() over(partition by EmployeeCode, EntryType order by TIME) rn
   from mytable
   )t
group by EmployeeCode, rn
order by EmployeeCode, rn
```

Otherwise a kind of clean-up is required first.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that may work is using inner joins .. as you may have multiple In & Out records.

```
Select A.EmployeeCode,
       Min(TIME) IN_TIME,
       (Select Max(A2.TIME) From Attendance A2 Where A2.EmployeeCode = A.EmployeeCode And A2.EntryType = 'OUT') OUT_TIME
From Attendance  A
Where A.EntryType = 'IN'
Group By A.EmployeeCode
```

So, The main query get the max Out time for each employee & the inner query get the min In time. That solution supposes that at least each employee has one IN record

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are always pairs of `IN/OUT`, you can use `LEAD` to get the next value

```sql
select
  EmployeeCode, 
  TIME as IN_TIME,
  nextTime AS OUT_TIME
from ( 
   select *,
     lead(case EntryType when 'OUT' then TIME end) over (partition by EmployeeCode order by TIME) nextTime
   from mytable
) t
where EntryType = 'IN';
```