# Getting two columns out of a single column with case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with languages of persons. Any person can either speak English, Spanish or both English and Spanish. In the first two cases I have one row per person_id, in the second I have two rows.

I need to use this data in another table but I can only retain one unique row per person. The correct solution in my case is to create two columns:

```
Select
 person_id,
 case when person_language = 'English' then person_language end as "english_language",
 case when person_language = 'Spanish' then person_language end as "spanish_language"
from person_table;
```

This gets the right data into the right column, but the English & Spanish are each shown on two separate rows having a NULL value in the other language column. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert Rows to Columns in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858079/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
Select
 person_id,
 max(case when person_language = 'English' then person_language end) as "english_language",
 max(case when person_language = 'Spanish' then person_language end) as "spanish_language"
from person_table
group by person_id;
```

This could also be done with the `pivot` syntax:

```
select person_id, english_language, spanish_language
from person_table
pivot (
  max(person_language) as language
  for (person_language) in ('English' as english, 'Spanish' as spanish)
)
order by person_id;
```

but it's the same mechanism underneath.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=86f34b3f2bf3938aecd895b94b88579e)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Which one of the two would be fastest to implement? It's going into a view with many rows and joins & dependencies on other tables

Comment: Pivot is converted to aggregation in the background anyway, so I doubt there would be much difference. Pivot is maybe easier to maintain if you have a lot of values, or need to add values, but I'd use whichever makes most sense to you.